# Categorize images uploaded

Tags: taxonomy-terms, media

How could i make it available for the admin to be able to upload images and categorize them in add content window? I added a taxonomy vocabulary and added a field as a taxonomy term to the content type but it only shows the terms from that vocabulary . I also would like to be able to upload an image for that term. Is it possible?

Comment: What version of Drupal do you use, 6 or 7 ?

Comment: @khaljava version 7